# Flutter get Download Url from Firebase Storage having error using "onComplete" function

Tags: firebase, flutter

I m trying to get images for my product thumnail. But I'm having problem using "onComplete" here. I try using "future" too but it still has the same problem.
This are my firebase dependany:
firebase_core: ^0.5.2
firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3
firebase_database: ^4.3.0
firebase_storage: ^5.0.1
firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.1

```
Future<List<String>> uploadProductImages(
      {Map<int, File> imageList, String docID}) async {
    List<String> imagesUrl = List();
    try {
      for (int s = 0; s < imageList.length; s++) {
        Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child(appProducts)
            .child(docID)
            .child(docID + "$s.jpg");
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageList[s]);
        Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete).downloadUrl;
        imagesUrl.add(downloadUrl.toString());
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      imagesUrl.add(error);
      print(e.message);
    }
    return imagesUrl;
  }
```

Comment: could you please post the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL from `StorageReference` i.e `storageReference.getDownloadURL()`

```
     Future<List<String>> uploadProductImages({
    Map<int, File> imageList,
    String docID,
    String appProducts,
  }) async {
    List<String> imagesUrl = List();
    try {
      for (int s = 0; s < imageList.length; s++) {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child(appProducts)
            .child(docID)
            .child(docID + "$s.jpg");
        final StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
            storageReference.putFile(imageList[s]);
        StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
        String downloadUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
        imagesUrl.add(downloadUrl.toString());
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      imagesUrl.add(error.code);
      print(error.message);
    }
    return imagesUrl;
  }
```